# I have an excel file which has a chart drawn in it. How can I import this chart into a Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

Currently my chart code looks like this:

```
 private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create the Application object we can use in the member functions.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            _excelApp.Visible = true;

        string fileName = "C:/Users/Desktop/UP and DOWN data.xlsx"; 


        //open the workbook
        Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        //select the first sheet        
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

        //find the used range in worksheet
        Range excelRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

        //get an object array of all of the cells in the worksheet (their values)
        object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
                    XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesUP = this.chart1.Series.Add("UP");
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesDOWN = this.chart1.Series.Add("DOWN");
        seriesUP.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        seriesDOWN.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        //access the cells
        for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++col)
            {
                //access each cell
                if (row != 1)
                {

                    if (col == 1)//get UP data only
                        seriesUP.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDouble(valueArray[row, col]), Convert.ToDouble(valueArray[row, col + 1]));
                    // Debug.Print(valueArray[row, col].ToString());
                    if (col == 3)//get DOWN data only

                        seriesDOWN.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDouble(valueArray[row, col]), Convert.ToDouble(valueArray[row, col + 1]));
                }
            }
        }

        //clean up stuffs
        workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

        _excelApp.Quit();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
}
```

This above attempts to draw a chart which takes too long for large datasets. How can I access the same workbook and extract the chart that is already drawn on it and display that on the winform?

Comment: It looks like you have the excel integration, why are you recreating the data sets locally? For instance, set the workbook sheet to active, find the chart in it and set it to active, then return it as a chart? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbook_members.aspx)

Comment: The chart is rendered by MS Excel, you cannot take it as image. MS Excel does not store the chart as image. Maybe you can find a tool that extracts a chart from Excel as image.

You should identify what takes time, loading data from Excel or setting the chart in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series and optimize maybe each part. Microsoft.Office.Interop is also slow.